# Defining Label.Text leads to a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I am trying to set a label to show some text when an error occurs. When I make this error occur, the label throws a NullReferenceException.

Here is the label.Text code from the code behind:

```
if (userEmail != null)
            {
                //If the same email exists
                pnlError.Visible = Visible;
                lblError.Text = "Error: The email you have entered is already assigned to an account.";
```

}

When I build, I get no errors, which would suggest to me that it is able to find it in the ASPX code.

Here it is in the markup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlError" runat="server" Visible="false" EnableViewState="false">
       <label id="lblError"></label>
        </asp:Panel>
```

As you can see it is wrapped in a panel. I can change the visibility of the panel just fine in the same function as the Label.Text

And here it is defined in the aspx.designer.cs:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel pnlError;
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblError;
```

It is worth mentioning, that whenever I change any other WebControl elements in the markup, such as a button or panel, the aspx.design.cs regenerates, but it fails to include the lblError label. I have tried deleting and then regenerating the design manually to no avail.

Comment: You're missing `runat="server"`.

Comment: adding runat="server" to the label tag results in about 6 errors.

Comment: I created a simple web application, and added the content you have, plus a `runat="server"`. I had to change the code to `lblError.InnerText` because it is an `HtmlGenericControl` in the aspx.designer.cs file. Did you maybe intend to use an `<asp:Label>` instead of a `<label>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the label is inside of a panel you need to find it:

```
if (userEmail != null)
{
    //If the same email exists
    pnlError.Visible = Visible;
    var lblError= ((Label)(pnlError.FindControl("lblError")));
    if(lblError != null)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Error: The email you have entered......";
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

You better use asp control

```
<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

then you dont need to find it

```
pnlError.Visible = Visible;
lblError.Text = "Error: The email you have entered......";
```

Comment: That solves the NullReferenceError exception but it doesn't update the label's text. The label text is just whatever is put into the markup.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't realise that sooner!